# How to draw a line with simple linear gradient in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Can't understand how to draw a line, which is SKShapeNode, and fill it with linear gradient. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

A custom `strokeShader` is what you want.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode/controlling_shape_drawing_with_shaders

Comment: It's very complicated way if you don't know shader language 

Comment: It's a lot less complicated than any other method that will work with SpriteKit .  The shader language is basically C/C++, and the first example on that page is showing a black-to-yellow gradient.  You just need to set `gl_FragColor` based on a simple linear interpolation between your starting and ending colors.